# How to run a telegram bot in django?

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

I want to run a telegram bot in django and have it run with the command "python manage.py runserver".

I tried to do this with subprocess, but it gives an error and because of this there is a conflict with the launch of several bots. Is there an alternative solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import call


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoProject7.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "main.py"])
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get ?

Comment: Please review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910699/start-telegram-bot-on-django-project) based on your needs